# How to generate incremental order number for multi-user environment

Tags: php, mysql

hope everyone is doing great. I'm trying to generate an incremental order/invoice number in a multiuser environment

This code works fine for a single-user environment. but how to achieve the same thing in a multi-user environment.

For example, there are two users (User A and User B)

User A has generated two invoices, then the order/invoice number would be like this INV-0000001, INV-0000002

User B has generated three invoices, then the order/invoice number would be like this INV-0000001, INV-0000002, INV-0000003

User Table
user_id is an auto-incremental and primary key

```
User_id | user_name | user_email | user_pass
1       | xyz       | xyz        | xyz
2       | xyz       | xyz        | xyz
```

Sale Table

sale_id is an auto-incremental and primary key and user_id in the sale table acts as a foreign key
Let's say there is an invoice_number column! This is what I'm trying to achieveeve

```
sale_id | user_id | invoice_number | sale_customer_name and so on
1       | 1       | INV-0000001    | xyz    
2       | 1       | INV-0000002    | xyz      
3       | 2       | INV-0000001    | xyz     
4       | 2       | INV-0000002    | xyz     
5       | 2       | INV-0000003    | xyz
```

sale_id is an auto incremental id

```
$select_invoice = "select * from sale where user_id='$user_id' order by sale_id desc limit 0,1";
$select_invoice_query = mysqli_query($connection, $select_invoice);
$invoice_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_invoice_query);
$invoice_result = $invoice_array['sale_id'];
$invoice_result++;
$invoice_result = "INV-".str_pad($invoice_result, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: what is sale_id used for?

Comment: sale_id is an auto-incremental id. @Psycho

Comment: In your query, you are not using any where condition for the result to be for specific user. So, in my opinion this automatically work for multiuser incremental invoice number.

Comment: suppose, the user A has issued invoice 0000001 and then when the user B tries to issue another invoice, the result should return 1, thus incrementing it the invoice for user B will be 0000002

Comment: Yep, you just need to expand the query to filter only the existing invoices of the specific user instead of all of them. Nothing more than a `WHERE` condition.

Comment: I can assign the user_id in where condition but how to start each user_id from 1. Basically, each user needs to have their own incremental id that starts from 1 @Psycho

Comment: El_Vanja already answered that, you just need to use a where condition in your query: `where user_id = $user['id']`

Comment: That's not a problem. When a user doesn't have any invoices, you will get no results. In that case, you will manually start from 1.

Comment: you are confusing invoice with user_id, just tell me who is currently logged in, user A or user B (for example)? @anonymous

Comment: @anonymous you can just add the code how you can get the user_id, then we can write you the complete query

Comment: I think you didn't get it! You just said that if user A has issued an invoice 0000001 and then when user B tries to issue an invoice, then it will be an invoice 0000002. I want to start invoice number from 0000001 for each user @Psycho

Comment: Can you please provide the definition of your table **by editing your question**?

Comment: Ahan! I got your point now! So this will basically start the invoice number from 0000001 for each user, right? @El_Vanja

Comment: YES... That's why I said earlier that El_Vanja already answered that. Just use a `where user_id = $user['id']` in your query

Comment: I just tried this method but unfortunately, it didn't work! My code would basically check the last id and then increment it! As I said earlier, sale_id is an auto-incremental id, each user needs to have their own incremental id that starts from one! Else it wouldn't work @Psycho

Comment: I think I just found out why it is not working. sale_id is a primary, auto-incremental id! Because of being the primary key! But as far as I know, we cannot have two auto-incremental ids in one table @Psycho

Comment: brother please listen to us carefully. We are talking about USER_ID......NOT SALE_ID..... Show us all columns of your `users` (the table used to authenticate/login) table and also all columns of `sales` table. I will tell you the next steps @anonymous

Comment: Already another user told you to show the table but you are not listening to us, we can't help you if you don't provide what we ask you @anonymous

Comment: I updated the question! You can see the table structure now @Psycho

Comment: You can see the table structure now @DefinitelynotRafal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: make sure the variable `$user_id` has value. Then change your query to:

```php
$select_invoice = "select * from sale where user_id=$user_id order by sale_id desc";
$select_invoice_query = mysqli_query($connection, $select_invoice);
$invoice_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_invoice_query);
$invoice_result = mysqli_num_rows($select_invoice_query);
$invoice_result++;
$invoice_result = "INV-".str_pad($invoice_result, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This will automatically filter the invoice results according to user_id foreign_key and thus, you will only get the invoices for the current/logged-in user.

### **For clarification:**

Suppose,
**users** table:

```
| User_id | user_name | user_email | user_pass |
| ------- | --------- | ---------- | --------- |
| 1       | user A    | email A    | pass A    |
| 2       | user B    | email B    | pass B    |
```

***Note:*** `user_id` is **primary key** here.

**Sales** table:

```
| sale_id | user_id | sale_customer_name |
| ------- | ------- | ------------------ |
| 1       | 1       | sale 1             |
| 2       | 1       | sale 2             |
| 3       | 2       | sale 3             |
| 4       | 2       | sale 4             |
| 5       | 2       | sale 5             |
```

***Note:*** `user_id` is **foreign key** here and **primary key** is `sale_id`.

Now, when you are trying to get sales for a specific user, for example let's say user A is logged in. Make sure you get the `user_id` from logged in user, maybe from session or maybe depends on how you are getting the logged_in_user_info. So, the query will get result for user A only (2 results: sale1 and sale2) because of the Where condition `[select * from sales where user_id=$logged_in_user_id order by sale_id desc limit 0,1]`  in sales table. You are running the query in sales table.

Now, when user B is logged in and you run the above query from sales table, it will get 3 results ( sale3, sale4, sale5).

Now, If you have another user C who has no invoices till now. Then by running the query will return 0 results because there are no invoices for user C. The where condition filters the results for other users and returns 0 results for user C. Thus, the invoice for user C must be INV-0000001 for user C.

Comment: Brother, I already tried this code but it didn't return the result I was expecting. As I said, each invoice number needs to start from 1 for every user. @Psycho

Comment: Suppose user A has issued two invoices, then the user will be assigned these numbers (INV-0000001, INV-0000002). Now when the user B logged in and issued an invoice bill, then the user B has been assigned this number INV-0000003 instead of INV-0000001

Comment: and as you know, $user_id is a primary and auto-incremental id! The value assigned automatically when user created an account

Comment: `user_id` is **primary key** in `users` table, it is **foreign key** in `sales` table, am i wrong? your query us running in sales table, right?

Comment: please share the code how you are getting `user_id` before running the query. I completely understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You are right! user_id is a primary key in the user's table and it is a foreign key in the sales table. Whenever an invoice bill is issued, then that user user_id is also get inserted in sales_table.  @Psycho

Comment: check the clarification I added above and let me know what you don't understand and please show me how you are getting the LOGGED IN USER INFO

Comment: Oh, looks like you misunderstood my question! I know how to fetch the data user-wise but this is not what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to echo out the invoice number in sequential order for each user and I'm getting the user_id with the help of sessions @Psycho

Comment: show the output you are getting after running this query.

Comment: That code would just keep incrementing the number! Let me explain to you! In the sale table, you have shown that user A has issued two invoices and then the invoice number would look like this (INV-000001,000002)

Comment: Now when user b logged in and issued three invoices, then the invoice number would look like this ((INV-000003,000004,000005) but this is not what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: It just keeps incrementing regardless of which user logged in

Comment: check the sale_table again! That is what I'm trying to achieve! Did you get it now? @Psycho

Comment: I know that you want to achieve from the 3rd/4th comment in your question. Tell me did you try the query or just saying this thinking your logic ? can you show us the output you are getting after running the query

Comment: The code that you provided me basically checks the user_id and increment it and then outputs the invoice numbers! If user d has been assigned an user_id 4, then it would start from INV-00000005. This is what it outputs

Comment: Okay, if user D is logged in, suppose there are no invoices for him till now. what will the query return ? filtering with where $user_id will get 0 results right? because there are no invoices for user D

Comment: Yes, When user D has not issued an invoice, then it would output INV-0000001 but after issuing the first invoice, it directly jumps to the INV-0000005 for the next invoice. because user_id is 4 and it increments by one, which makes it 5

Comment: that's impossible brother, now the user D has only one sale for him. The query will look for sales only for user D (because of the WHERE condition) and the result must be 1. Thus the next invoice must be INV-0000002

Comment: just think clearly, the same query that returns 0 results for user D because there are no invoices for user D, how can it result 4 when there is only 1 result for user D.....!!!! Impossible

Comment: Check your code! it is incrementing the invoice number according to the user_id. So it is obvious that it would output INV-0000005 because user D is having user_id 4

Comment: I'm talking about this! $invoice_result = $invoice_array['user_id'];
$invoice_result++;

Comment: `$invoice_result = $invoice_array['user_id'];` this line ?

Comment: even this wouldn't work! because it would then increment according to the sale_id which is unique for every invoice or sale

Comment: okay, you need to ***count*** it! my appologies. `$invoice_result = mysqli_num_rows($invoice_array);`

Comment: No need to apologize! You are helping me out here! I should be thankful to you for it! I'm wondering how counting would solve this problem? Could you please explain?

Comment: Ahan got it! It would count the rows of only specific users and then increment according to that, right?

Comment: Explanation: user A has 2 sales/invoices, user B has 3 sales/invoices, user D has 1 sales/invoices. so if the user D is now logged in, the query will return only 1 result and the  counting will return 1. So, your invoice will be inv-0000002 for user D

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! But for some known reason, it is returning this error mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, I rechecked the syntax

Comment: does this happen because we added an array inside mysqli_num_rows?  But that shouldn't be the problem, right? because that's how this thing supposed to work

Comment: the error is gone after writing this code $invoice_result = mysqli_num_rows($select_invoice_query);

Comment: Finally, it works! Thank you so much, brother! But there is still one problem. it stops at INV-0000002. After that, it stops incrementing! Weird

Comment: stops for the next invoice? really weird now!

Comment: We can add the next invoice after that! but the invoice number doesn't increase after INV-0000002.

Comment: I believe problem lies in this line $select_invoice = "select * from invoice_order where user_id={$user_id} order by sale_id desc limit 0,1";

Comment: Figured it out! This works $select_invoice = "select * from invoice_order where user_id={$user_id}";

Comment: once again thank you so much! You are awesome! my life would have messed up without you! You can answer the question if you want!

Comment: oh, limit 1 is the problem now, increase it like 10 or 100

Comment: You're welcome, we are already commenting in my answer! You can accept and upvote it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231862/discussion-between-psycho-and-anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the order number after generating it, when it's ended.

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer. What do you mean by "when its ended"?